# need help for developing android restaurant menu application

Tags: android

I want to develop restaurant menu application
functions: application contains list of items available in restaurant. waiter takes order from customer by selecting various items in the list. On submitting order it goes to chef,who has android device with him, he will ack the requested order.

i want to simulate this app on emulator, i have designed some basic interface. problems is that i want to transfer selected item data to other application running on other emulator,in short communication between two application running on different device. What should i do ? as far as my knowledge AIDL feature of android facilitates common between two app running on the same device.
thanks!!

Comment: How do you plan to have the devices talk to each other? That question seems independent of how to test your app in the emulator(s) - which should be able to work the same way.

Comment: @CrackerJack9:i just want to simulate this project, don't want to run on actual device. if 2 devices communicate via blutooth ,then how to transfer list of ordered items ? and how to run bluetooth related projects on emulator , because i have seen that sample blutooth chat application provided with sdk, didn't run on emulator. Thanks for considering my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth is [not currently available](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#limitations) available in the Android emulator, but some people seem to have had luck with [this github project](https://github.com/cheng81/Android-Bluetooth-Simulator).

Answer (score 1):

As for most of all inter device communications, you are better of using a server in between.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bluetooth or email the order from one device to another.

Comment: if i use bluetooth then ,how to run bluetooth related project on emulator? because i just want to show simulation of this project.

Comment: You should have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html.

Comment: @ CrackerJack9 : which answer?